# Emacs cannot save customizations- init file not fully loaded

Tags: unix, ubuntu, emacs, lisp

When I try to check the "do not show this screen again" box and save at the Emacs default start buffer, I get an error: `custom-save-all: Cannot save customizations, init file not fully loaded`

My full output looks like:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...
No /etc/mailname. Reverting to default...
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/slime/slime-autoloads.elc...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el (source)...done
Loading /home/nathan/elisp/autoloads...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
(New file)
custom-save-all: Cannot save customizations; init file was not fully loaded
```

I have been tinkering with my `.emacs` file to no avail.  It looks like this (I am trying to get `install.el` to work properly):

```
(load "~/elisp/autoloads" 'install)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp")
(require 'install.el)
```

If I try to `C - X - C - E` this code, I get errors in the buffer:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Required feature `install.el' was not provided")
  require(install\.el)
  eval((require (quote install\.el)))
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

`~/elisp` directory is present, and that's where my `*.el` files are located.  So I'm kind of confused what's going wrong, as it seems I have the proper path names and syntax.

Any help would be amazing.  Thank you, fellow Emacs hackers!

Comment: My opinion is that although the emacs configuration file is lisp code, this is still a "using emacs" question because it seems some part of your standard emacs environment is missing or misconfigured and thus it is off topic.  Voted to close.

Comment: I see this as a good fit for superuser too.

Comment: Closely related: [emacs error cannot save customizations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491094/emacs-error-cannot-save-customizations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use:

```
(require 'install)
```

without the .el

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.  I knew I was overlooking something obvious.